# qsort not working correctly because of null pointer

Tags: c

Code:

```
struct company_struct
{
    company_name_t company_name;
    double stock_price;
    company_stock_t company_stock;
};

typedef struct company_struct company_struct_t;


int sort_by_price(const void * ptr1, const void * ptr2)
{
    assert(ptr1 != NULL);
    assert(ptr2 != NULL);

    const company_struct_t * ptr1_price = (const company_struct_t *) ptr1;
    const company_struct_t * ptr2_price = (const company_struct_t *) ptr2;

    assert(ptr1_price->stock_price != NULL); //??? Why it failed?
    assert(ptr2_price->stock_price != NULL);

    if(ptr1_price->stock_price > ptr2_price->stock_price) return -1;
    else if (ptr1_price->stock_price == ptr2_price->stock_price) return 0;
    else if (ptr1_price->stock_price < ptr2_price->stock_price) return 1;

}


qsort(company_list, *size, sizeof(company_list), sort_by_price);
```

When I run my program, the assert failed. I am relatively new to C, please bear with me.

Comment: the size has to be the initial size of the array or the number of existed elements?

Comment: One is the size of a single datum, the other is the number of data elements in the array. Not sure which is which without checking the manpage.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to pass the size of an individual element as the third parameter of [`qsort`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/qsort), like this:

```
qsort(company_list, *size, sizeof(company_struct_t), sort_by_price);
```

Also make sure that `size` points to an `int` that holds the number of items to be sorted.

Answer (score 0):

If it really is this line that's failing,

```
assert(ptr1_price->stock_price != NULL); //??? Why it failed?
```

you should crank-up your compiler warnings. You should get a warning for comparing a `double` to a pointer. [And for prices, it's usually better to use an integer. What would $0.000003 mean?]